# Map sql query with EF query doesn't work

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

i am trying to execute a query using EF6 .my query in sql format is like this :

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT 
      [SUBJECT],COUNT(SUBJECT)

  FROM [PGC].[dbo].[QC] group by [SUBJECT]
```

It works great.

The subject is a string type.

But  i translate the query to EF as you can see here :

```
 listDataSource =
                db.QCs.Where(j => j.SUBJECT != null).ToList().GroupBy(i => new {i.SUBJECT}).Select(m => new chart()
                    {
                        date = m.Key.SUBJECT,
                        Count = m.Count(i=>i.SUBJECT).ToString()
                    }).ToList();
```

**m.Count(i=>i.SUBJECT)** returns an error :`can't convert expression type string to return type bool`

best regards

Comment: Your SUBJECT field is string, you cannot count strings, only boolean expressions. It is identical to .Where(i => {some boolean expression}).Count()

Comment: My question is if it's not possible why sql can count it?

Comment: Because LINQ does not directly translates to SQL, nor vise versa. Expressions perfectly valid in one do not make any sense in another. And that's the main sin of LINQ: it looks like SQL, behaves otherwise and it's real nature is functional processing of data streams (through methods known as map,filter,flatMap, etc.). If you really want to know how your LINQ translates to SQL, use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on Yuriy's answer (which is perfectly acceptable), with a couple of fixes, mostly for performance sake:

```
listDataSource = db.QCs
    .Where(j => j.SUBJECT != null)
    .GroupBy(i => i.SUBJECT) //no need to create an anonymous type, you don't use it afterwards
    .Select(group => new { SUBJECT = group.Key, Count = group.Count()}) //counting in SQL is faster
    .AsEnumerable() //materialization, all the heavy lifting is performed by SQL until now
    .Select(value => //seems redundant, but the previous selection just translates into an SQL select statement with SUBJECT and Count columns
        new chart
        {
            date = value.SUBJECT,
            Count = value.Count.ToString()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)` because it:

> Returns a number that represents how many elements in the specified sequence satisfy a condition.[<sup>Source</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx)

`i=>i.SUBJECT` is a `Func<TSource, String>` but the method expects `Func<TSource, Boolean>` and that's why you receive that exception message.

Instead use `Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` which will return the total number of elements in a sequence, e.g.:

```
 Count = m.Count().ToString()
```

Comment: So i don't need the total number in sequence ,i need the total number that is grouped by my subject column

Comment: @EA, your variable `m` is an IGrouping<TKey, TValue>, invoking `Count()` on it will give you the number of items in that group only.

Comment: And that's what you get, once you are after GroupBy, you count the number of items in a single group

Comment: I did it it gives me the total number of the list